# How do you extract data from a string with no spaces in python

Tags: python, formatting

I have a python project to take variables from a long string that looks something like this:

```
FNAMEMYNAMELNAMEMYLASTNAMEEND
```

There are prefixes like `FNAME` and `LNAME` but the prefix for the next value is the suffix for the first value.

I'm looking to take values between the prefix example "MYNAME" and use as a variable. My main issue is the length of the string is always different and the values in the string are always a different length.

Main issue being all names are different lengths. And not everyone has a middle name so some values may not be present at all.

I have tried using the split function and it finds the prefixes, but it gives me the rest of the string as a output. I am looking to find a way to tell the split function to start the split at FNAME but stop at LNAME.

Herse what I have so far.

```
f = open('filename.txt', 'r') # Open  txt file

filename = f.read() # Take string from file and attribute to variable "filename" 

f.close() # Close txt file

print(filename.split("FNAME",1)[1]) # split sting if prefix FNAME is found
```

The code will output `MYNAMELNAMEMYLASTNAMEEND`

As a added bonus the vary last `END` suffix may not always be present

I'm sure split is not the best function to use for this but its the only one that showed me any progress. Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: Does middle name (presumably MNAME) come in between FNAME and LNAME ? Or do any other tags come in between FNAME and LNAME for that matter?

Comment: What happens if someone's last name ends with `END`? How do you know if that's part of their name or the `END` suffix?

Comment: There is nothing between FNAME and LNAME I was using MNAME as a example of a value that may not be entered by the user. as of now there is no middle name prefix that I have seen the data I have to go through. My main goal is to make this code as fault tolerant as possible. and that was the best example I had. I think the data will always be in the same order though.

Comment: Are you considering `FNAME` and  `LNAME` as prefixes while `END` as suffix?

Comment: I'm not sure what easier to process Keep in mind that there also is trash data before the prefix and trash data after the suffix. I don't know if its easier to take FNAME through END make a new string and chop it up and extract the values I need. OR treat FNAME to LNAME as its own item and get the values from the main long string one my one.

Comment: @RantWhy, if `END` is optional, how do you know where to stop reading the characters after the `LNAME` prefix?, There must be some delimiter to help you decide where to stop if `END` is not there. May be it's better if you gave the whole picture of your issue and this way of handling it is just wasting efforts. Probably there might a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression.

```
import re

with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    line = f.readline().strip()
match = re.search(r'^FNAME(.*)LNAME(.*)$', line)
if match:
    fname = match.group(1)
    lname = match.group(2)
    lname = re.sub('END$', '', lname) # remove END if it exists
```

Comment: This won't work in case `line` does not have `END` at the end, as described by OP.

Comment: The code looks to work great Thank you. I only have 1 problem in the strings that I will be running this code on there is also a lot of trash at the beginning and end before it gets to the prefixes and suffixes. In other words If there is any characters before the prefix the code will not make a match. same with the end. To make matters worse the number of trash characters are different for every string I will be running. so I cant do any fixed character removal.

Comment: You can get rid of the `^` anchor to find `FNAME` anywhere. But I don't know how you can handle garbage at the end if the `END` suffix is optional.